# Eigenvalues of hermitian plus skew-hermitian PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was wondering, suppose you have a matrix of the form $A=B+iCC^\dagger$ where $^\dagger$ denotes the hermitian conjugate. $B$ is hermitian and $CC^\dagger$ is obviously hermitian positive semi-definite.

Is it true that if $A \psi = 0$, then $B \psi = 0$ and $C^\dagger \psi = 0$? If so, how can I prove it? My idea was to look at $\psi^\dagger A \psi$, but to no avail.

If it is not true, what would be a counter-example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that if $D$ is a Hermitian matrix and $v$ is a vector then $v^\dagger D v\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thus, if $Av=0$ then $0=v^\dagger Av=v^\dagger Bv+i(v^\dagger CC^\dagger v)$.

Since  $v^\dagger Bv \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $v^\dagger CC^\dagger v\in \mathbb{R}$ then $v^\dagger Bv=v^\dagger CC^\dagger v=0$. But this implies that $C^\dagger v=0$, since $CC^\dagger$ is positive semidefinite.

Therefore, $Av=0=Bv+iCC^\dagger v=Bv$.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @Yamamoto you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use $*$ to denote the conjugate transpose.

Thoughts so-far:

> **Lemma:** for a matrix $M$ and vector $x$, $Mx = 0 \iff M^*Mx = 0$

Note that
$$
\psi^*(B + iCC^*)\psi = (\psi^*B\psi) + i(\psi^*CC^*\psi)
$$
Noting that $(\psi^*B\psi),(\psi^*CC^*\psi) \in \Bbb R$, we conclude that
$$
\psi^* A \psi = 0 \iff (\psi^*B\psi) = (\psi^*CC^*\psi) = 0\\
\Longleftarrow B\psi = C^*\psi = 0
$$
We then note that
$$
A\psi = 0 \implies \psi^*A\psi = 0
$$
(though the converse does not necessarily hold).

Comment: But $B$ is neither positive nor negative definite. Isn't $\psi^* M \psi = 0 \implies M \psi = 0$ wrong in that case ?

Comment: $\left(1,1 \right) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: You have a point; not sure how I missed that. I'll think about it.

Comment: I would be grateful for a proof (or a counter-example).

Comment: I think it's true for $\psi \in \Bbb R^n$, but not for $\psi \in \Bbb C^n$

Comment: Intuitively I'd say it is not true, too but so far I have not been able to construct a counter-example.

Comment: I'll admit this problem is more complicated than I expected

Comment: Does it help to split $\psi = \psi^\prime + \mathrm{i} \psi^{\prime \prime}$ with $\psi^\prime, \psi^{\prime \prime} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: It's definitely true for $\psi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ because then $\psi^{\prime \prime} = 0$ and $(B + \mathrm{i} C C^\dagger) \psi^\prime = 0$. Without loss of generality you may assume that $C C^\dagger$ is diagonal with positive real entries.

Comment: But $B$ might have complex entries, which muddies things up a bit. Yes, it helps to note that one of the matrices can be diagonal without loss of generality.

Comment: You are right, my argumentation is not valid. This problem is not trivial at all.